# OpenCV on IOS haar cascade xml file path issues from C++

Tags: c++, ios, xml, opencv, filepath

So I have my code in C++ and I am able to run it fine on linux/OSX/Android.  The problem now is ios.  I am simply trying to load the haar cascade xml files via full path "/foo/blah/myapp.app/haar.xml" and having one heck of a time.

C++ can't confirm the file exists nor can opencv load it.  I am new to ios and am aware that the myapp.app could be a compressed dir like the android .apk dir.

I have confirmed that I'm looking in the right place....or at least I hope I have! to check i use getcwd in c++ to get running directory and I confirm that with the file path to the xml file.  It looks legit!

What can I do?  The nice part about using C++ for the lib is that I can use one code base for desktop/android/ios.  I really don't want to have to mix in Objective-C into my lib just for file paths.

Thanks in advance!

The code I'm using is the following:

```
    std::ifstream fexists(face_haar_path.c_str());
    if(!fexists.good()) {
        std::cout << "Could not find any facehaar.xml" << std::endl;
        return NO_FACE_HAAR_FILE;
    }

    face_haar.load(face_haar_path); //cv::CascadeClassifier face_haar
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding reference to file location in iOS apps is quite different. First add the `.xml` files to your Xcode project and use the following lines of code for loading the haar-cascade. Please note that  should not contain the extension `.xml` (Example: For `face_frontal.xml` file, your cascade name should be `face_frontal`)

```
NSString *faceCascadePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                             pathForResource:@"<your_cascade_name>"
                             ofType:@"xml"];
const CFIndex CASCADE_NAME_LEN = 2048;
char *CASCADE_NAME = (char *) malloc(CASCADE_NAME_LEN);
CFStringGetFileSystemRepresentation( (CFStringRef)faceCascadePath,
                                    CASCADE_NAME,
                                    CASCADE_NAME_LEN);
if(!face_cascade.load(CASCADE_NAME)) {
    cout << "Unable to load the face detector!!!!" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}
```